# prevent infinite loop when calling setState in useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If I add `movement` to the useCallback dependency array I get an infinite loop, but without it I get warnings to add it.

What is the correct way of dealing with this, whilst keeping the state as an object?

```
// state
const [
    { movement, start, ..., ..., ...},
    setState,
  ] = useState({
    movement: 0,
    start: 0,
    ....    ,
    ....    ,
    ....    ,

...

// handler
const handleMouseMove = useCallback(
    ({ xpos }) => {
      const walk = xpos - start
      const atStart = walk + movement > 0
      setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        movement: atStart ? 0 : walk + movement,
      }))
    },
    [start]
  )
```

Comment: is there a reason why you're even putting it into `useCallback`?

Comment: I can change to useEffect but I think I'd still get the infinite loop issues

Comment: just use a regular function?

Comment: Since your callback potentially updates a value in its dependency array then you need to do a check first before updating global (within function) state object, similar to `componentDidUpdate` when you compare previous and current state/prop values before calling `setState`. Your `atStart` logic doesn't quite make sense to me so I'm not sure *what* that condition to test for would be.

Answer (score 2):

When using `React.useState` make sure not to store objects. Here you should create 2 different state variables for `movement` and `start`. That should fix your issue.

If you want to store a complex state, you can take a look at `React.useReducer` instead.

Comment: The thing is I have 10 other state variables in this state object

Comment: @Falko It isn't recommended to store complex objects in `useState` hooks. I'd say mostly due to the fact that you have to do your own deep state merging. Giving each piece of state it's own piece of state simplifies overall component "state" updates.

Comment: Thanks guys but I want to keep this state object. Have updated the question to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

```
      setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    movement: atStart ? 0 : walk + movement,
  }))
```

You're actually using updated movement in setState which cause it changes every time that cause infinite loop. You should use previousState movement on it.

```
      setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    movement: atStart ? 0 : walk + state.movement,
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove dependencies.

```
const handleMouseMove = useCallback(
  ({ xpos }) => {
    setState(state => {
      let walk = xpos - state.start
      let atStart = walk + state.movement > 0
      return {
        ...state,
        movement: atStart ? 0 : walk + state.movement,
      }
    })
  },
  []
)
```